# MVC4 model custom function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Sorry for newbie questions, i'm brand new to MVC and OOP

I have the following model for my USER db table

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int user_id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string salt { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public sbyte status { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime creation_date { get; set; }
        public sbyte type { get; set; }
        public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
        public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }
        public virtual UserToken UserToken { get; set; }
        public virtual Veterinarian Veterinarian { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Actually in order to recall a particular USER based on the mail or the id i use a specific class called CustomDbFunctions

```
namespace MyApp.Models.DAL
{
    public static class CustomDbFunctions
    {
        public static User GetUserEntityFromEmail(string email, DbContext db)
        {
            return db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.email == (string)email);
        }
    }
}
```

in that way i use in my code

```
User user = CustomDbFunctions.GetUserEntityFromEmail(email, db)
```

and this it 100% OK with me, but i don't know if this kind of approach is correct or not, or if there's a better way like

```
//select the single user by calling only the class USER    
User mySelectedUser = new User(email)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: ok and what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that is not 100% clear how to achive that, if you can post me some example, that would be great,

Comment: ooh so you just want to know some ideas on how to design you'r data access layer?

Comment: @user3169037 this is very introductory stuff for MVC, have you done any tutorials yet? the easiest way is to query it in your controller: `context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.user_id == id);` If this is not what you want then you are going to have to elaborate on your question a bit more.

Comment: @SOfanatic my apology, i modified my question, hope now everything is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for understanding how to **access your data in your MVC4 application** you could read this tutorial [from the Asp.Net MVC main page](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4). Read the whole tutorial about MVC4 and you'll get a solid idea on how to work with it.

But I also recommend this tutorial on a **good Entityframework design pattern**, it's called [Repository Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/631668/Learning-MVC-Part-5-Repository-Pattern-in-MVC3-App), I just a nice way to get all your code ordered (like all other patterns). Let me know.